# Multithreaded Java proxy server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, http, proxy

I'm a bit new to Stack Overflow, so if I've done anything incorrectly, feel free to let me know. I haven't found another post that addresses this question in a way that makes sense to me yet.

So my end goal is to write a multithreaded HTTP proxy server in Java, but as a first step, I'm just trying to write the input stream of a connection established via my browser to the window.

Here is my code:

```
private static ServerSocket welcomeSocket;
private static Socket connectionSocket;

private static Socket clientSocket;

private static OutputStream clientOutput;
private static InputStream proxyInput;

private static BufferedReader reader;

private static InetSocketAddress clientStream;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    // Create socket, port 12345, for incoming request
    welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
    while(true){
        try(Socket clientSocket = welcomeSocket.accept()){
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

        Thread t = new Thread(){  
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("running\n");
                try{
                    System.out.println("trying\n");
                    String lineIn;
                    while((lineIn = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        System.out.println("writing\n");
                        writer.write(lineIn);
                        writer.newLine();
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException i){
                    try {                            
                        Logger.getLogger(EECS325_Project1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, i);
                        throw i;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(EECS325_Project1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        }
    }

}
```

However, when I go to localhost:12345 in my browser, I get the following exception:

```
     Nov 04, 2015 9:53:44 AM eecs325_project1.EECS325_Project1$1 run
     SEVERE: null
     java.net.SocketException: socket closed
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
     at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
     at eecs325_project1.EECS325_Project1$1.run(EECS325_Project1.java:46)
```

Most posts say that this exception occurs when one closes the reader/writer, effectively closing the socket. However, at no point do I close the reader, writer, or socket.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "However, at no point do I close the reader, writer, or socket." You do, when the try-with-resources finishes: `try(Socket clientSocket = welcomeSocket.accept()){`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you! I see the issue now, but I'm not sure of the appropriate way to fix it. I added a finally statement which closes the socket if it's not null, but it still seems to close before that. Any thoughts?

Comment: you need to "handoff" the socket to the thread.  after you successfully call start, set your local reference to the socket to null so that it no longer gets closed in the outer finally block.  since the thread will now own the socket, you need to ensure that the _thread_ closes the socket in a finally block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try-with-resources block closes the client socket before the Thread executes - meaning that `reader` and `writer` refer to closed underlying streams when the Thread tries to use them.

A solution to this to move the try-with-resources block to inside the thread:

```
final Socket clientSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
Thread t = new Thread(){  
  @Override public void run(){
    // BufferedReader/Writer close the underlying stream when they
    // are closed, so the socket will be closed when this
    // try-with-resources block finishes.
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())));
         BufferedWriter writer = ...) {
      // Do whatever.
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // Handle the exception.
    }
  }
};
t.start();
```

This means that the closing won't happen until the Thread is run, more specifically after you've finished doing things with `reader` and `writer`.

Note: You will have to take care to ensure that the Socket is *always* closed: this won't happen if there is an exception in creating the Thread, or in creating the BufferedReader. These cases are a bit grotty, and involve some extra try/catch/finally blocks; I'd rather not add these to the answer as I think that they just obscure the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
rivate static ServerSocket welcomeSocket;
private static Socket connectionSocket;

private static Socket clientSocket;

private static OutputStream clientOutput;
private static InputStream proxyInput;

private static BufferedReader reader;

private static InetSocketAddress clientStream;
```

Not one of these data items should be static, and the ones concerned with a specific client (the accepted socket, its upstream socket, and their streams) should be in a separate `Runnable` connection-handler class that is instantiated per accepted socket and a `Thread` created to run it.